# Energy spectral density in an LTI system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, control-theory, signal-processing

Consider the LTI system:
$$x\left( t \right) \to LTI\, system \to y\left( t \right) $$

The graph of the $x(t) $ signal is the following:

[image]

Remark: The graph when $t>0$ is a quarter of a circle.

Q1: Find
$$ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} X(\omega )d\omega $$
Q2: Find the energy spectral density of the output signal of the system, if the
unit impulse response is 
$$ h(t)=e^{7-t} u\left( t-7 \right)  $$
and the new input signal is $x_{2}(t)=x(t)[u(t+7)-u(t)] $ . The expression
$u(t)$ denotes the unit step function.

Q3: Find the energy of this last output signal.

---

Remark: In Q1, $X(w) $ denotes either Fourier transform or Laplace tranform, I am not sure. I think it most probably is Fourier transform.

**Edit:** Thanks to the help of @Stelios , I was able to solve Q1 (I think). The inverse Fourier transform is given by:
$$ f(x)=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat {f}}(\xi )\ e^{2\pi ix\xi }\,d\xi $$

However, in this case, we should use the [alternative version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_duality) of the inverse Fourier transform:
$$ x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega
$$
$$ \Rightarrow x( 0 )= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) e^{0} d\omega
$$

But, by looking at the graph, we know that $x(0)=16 $ .
$$ \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} X(w)dw =2\pi \, x(0)=32\pi $$

And that would be the answer to Q1.

Now, for Q2, I think I can find the output signal $y(t) $ by using the convolution integral.
$$ y(t)=(h*x_2)(t) =(x_2*h)(t) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau )[u(\tau +7)-u(\tau ) ]
e^{7-t+\tau } u(t-\tau -7) d\tau  $$

But the function $u_2(\tau ):= u(\tau +7)-u(\tau ) $ is equal to $1$ only when
$-7< \tau <0 $ . Therefore we will have:
$$ y(t)= \int_{-7}^{0} x(\tau ) )
e^{7-t+\tau } u(t-\tau -7) d\tau  $$

Then, for the case when $7<t $, we will have:
$$ y(t)=  \int_{-7}^{0} x(\tau )  e^{7-t+\tau } d\tau  $$

And for the case when $0<t<7 $, we will have:
$$ y(t)=  \int_{-7}^{t-7} x(\tau )  e^{7-t+\tau } d\tau  $$

And when $t<0 $, we will have $y(t)=0 $. Also, $x(\tau )=16 $ in the interval $[-7,0]$, then:

$$ y(t)= 
\begin{cases}
 0 \quad  & ; t<0 \\
 16 \left( 1-e^{-t} \right)  & ; 0<t<7
 \\
 16\, e^{-t} \left( e^7 -1 \right)   & ; 7<t
 \\
\end{cases}
$$

To find the energy:
$$ E_y =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \mid y(t) \mid ^2 dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \mid y(t) \mid ^2 dt $$

which should not be a complicated integral. Now, for the energy spectral density:
$$ S_{yy}=  \mid \hat{y} (f)  \mid ^2  $$

where $\hat{y} (f) $ denotes the Fourier transform of $y(t)$ , and $f$ denotes
the frequency. I then get:
$$ \hat{y}(f)= \int_0^{7} 16(1-e^{-t} )e^{2\pi ift} dt + \int_{7}^{\infty}
16(e^7 -1)e^{-2\pi ift} dt $$

Are all the steps above correct?

Comment: Recall the inverse Fourier transform: $x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega$. Do you see any similarity between the right hand side of this equation and the integral you are requested to find?

Comment: @Stelios , thanks for the reply. Yes, in that case the argument of the integral is just being multiplied by an exponential factor. Should I use integration by parts? Or something else?

Comment: The equation gives you directly the answer without the need to do any calculation yourself. How can the right-hand side become equal to the integral you want to compute?

Comment: @Stelios , oh! I think I see it now. When $t=0$, I would get the answer, which would be $2\pi x(0)=32\pi $ . Is that correct?

Comment: @Stelios , thanks for your help. I have updated my post.

Comment: According to [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Energy_spectral_density) the energy spectral density also considers negative time.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thanks for your comment. Taking into account that negative time, I have now updated my post.

Comment: @Stelios , your comment was very useful to find partially the answer. Would you mind please writing an answer so I can accept it? Even something very simple, just repeating what your comment says, would be fine.