# A piecewise function as the output signal of an LTI system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, control-theory, signal-processing

In an LTI system, consider the following:

> The input signal:
>   $$ x(t)= 
> \begin{cases}
>  16 \quad  & ; -7<t<0 \\
>  0  & ; \text{otherwise}  \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   And the unit impulse response:
>   $$ h(t)=e^{7-t} u\left( t-7 \right)  $$
>   Find the energy of the output signal and the energy spectral density of that
>   same output signal.

Remark: A related question is [Energy spectral density in an LTI system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288152/energy-spectral-density-in-an-lti-system)  .
First we find the output signal:
$$ y(t)=(x*h)(t)= 
\begin{cases}
 0 \quad  & ; t<0 \\
 16 \left( 1-e^{-t} \right)  & ; 0<t<7
 \\
 16\, e^{-t} \left( e^7 -1 \right)   & ; 7<t
 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then the energy will be:
$$ E_y =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \mid y(t) \mid ^2 dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \mid y(t) \mid ^2 dt $$

And I think I can solve that integral by hand. Now, the energy spectral density
will be:
$$ S_{yy}=  \mid \hat{y} (\xi)  \mid ^2  $$

So, first we find:
$$ \hat{y}(\xi)= \int_0^{7} 16(1-e^{-t} )e^{-2\pi i\xi t} dt + \int_{7}^{\infty}
16(e^7 -1)e^{-t}e^{-2\pi i\xi t} dt $$

To solve that by hand, I think I will have to go to WolframAlpha first and solve
integrals of the form $e^{(a+bi)t} $.

Are the steps above correct? Is there any way of solving this with less steps?

Comment: Convolution in time domain is multiplication in frequency domain...

Comment: @player100 thanks for the comment. Should I do something like $(y*y)(t) $ ? Or you are referring to something else?

Comment: I am suggesting to take the transform of $x$ and $h$, Multiply and take the absolute value